# How to do the checkboxfunctionality in MVc Asp.net using C# Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am having a edit client form in my application which is having an acheckbox labeled isActive and in the database the datatype of the isActive field is integer.The field isActive is not mandatory , the user can select it or else it cannot it is on his own wish.

I am receiving the below error If I am not selecting the checkbox 
"
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'status' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddFeedBack(System.String, System.String, Int32)' in 'BrandConnectionsPrototype.Controllers.AdminController'. To make a parameter optional its type should be either a reference type or a Nullable type.
Parameter name: parameters

"

Please tell  me some solution to this how can I handle this situation I am stuck up with this point from many days,I searched the net but could not find some useful solutions,if u have any good example or code please give me its  very urgent.

Thanks in advance
Ritz

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is that if not selected the checkbox does not appear ion the `Form` collection.

I do not use the HtmlHelper for checkbox and add my own in Html "by hand"

Then upon reaching my ActionMethod that accepts the Post, I "parse" my checkboxes, by that I mean I set the elements of my Model that correspond to the checkbox as the value of

```
Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains["MyCheckBoxName"]
```

Hope that helps!

Kindness,

Dan